# Face Detection - Open CV can't find the face

Tags: python, opencv3.0, face

I am learning the OpenCV. Here is my code:

```
import cv2
face_patterns = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
sample_image = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(sample_image,cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
faces = face_patterns.detectMultiScale(gray,1.3,5)
print(len(faces))
for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
    cv2.rectangle(sample_image, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
cv2.imwrite('result.jpg', sample_image)
```

If I use the picture A, I could get a lot of faces, if I use the picture B, I get none.

I changed argument in `detectMultiScale(gray,1.3,5)` many times, it still doesn't work.

[Picture A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/stGpf.jpg)

[Picture A Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mdYV.jpg)

[Picture B no face](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnaWc.jpg)

Comment: In my experience `Haar Cascade` does not work  with faces that are are tilted at an angle as in `Image B`.

Answer (score 1):

I see this more as a problem of Cv2 module itself. There are better models than HAAR CASCADES for detecting faces. face_recognition library is also very useful to detect and recognize face. It uses **hog** as default model. You can also use **cnn** for better accuracy but the detection process will be slow.

Find more [here](https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition).

```py
import cv2
import face_recognition as fr

sample_image = fr.load_image_file("1.jpg")
unknown_face_loc = fr.face_locations(sample_image, model="hog")
print(len(unknown_face_loc)) #detected face count
for faceloc in unknown_face_loc:
    y1, x2, y2, x1 = faceloc
    cv2.rectangle(sample_image, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 0, 255), 2)

sample_image = sample_image[:, :, ::-1] #converting bgr image to rbg
cv2.imwrite("result.jpg", sample_image)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Instead of -**

```
faces = face_patterns.detectMultiScale(gray,1.3,5)
```

**Try Using -**

```
faces = face_patterns.detectMultiScale(blackandwhite,1.3,5)
```

> If the problem occurs even after this check out my code for [face detection](https://github.com/idevesh/Crop-Faces-OpenCV).

Answer (score 0):

It uses hog as default model. You can also use cnn for better accuracy but the detection process will be slow.

````
cascade_classifier = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascades/haarcascade_eye.xml')
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    # Our operations on the frame come here
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, 0)
    detections = cascade_classifier.detectMultiScale(gray,scaleFactor=1.3,minNeighbors=5)
    if(len(detections) > 0):
        (x,y,w,h) = detections[0]
        frame = cv2.rectangle(frame,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)

    # for (x,y,w,h) in detections:
    #   frame = cv2.rectangle(frame,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()```
````